# webapi and jquery give me issues

Tags: jquery

I dont know much about the html. But for some reason my projects that use things like $(...) dont always work from web api. If I move my project off line and run it from my system they work.

Examples:

Using this **$(‘…’).bind(‘dragstart’…)** to move a window around works offline but on the webapi the events are not caught.

Using  **$(document).ready(function () {** seem to cause issues in finding references. removing the function and the code finds the reference.

using jqwidgets this line fails to fire   **$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid**

I'm completely out of ideas here, any thoughts?

---

### Adding my code here as the comments wont give enough room:

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>---</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=           "../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdata.export.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../../www/javascript/spreadSheet.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../../www/javascript/dataLoader.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../../www/javascript/windowMaker.js'></script>
<link href="../../www/window.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    canvas, img { display:block; margin:1em auto; border:1px solid black; }
    canvas { background:url(../../www/background.png) }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var loadedData = loadData();
    makeWindow();

    function init()//this is called after the data is loaded. So hult all other action untill its read. 
    {
        var data = loadedData[0].data.Name;
       // makeSpreadSheet()


    }

</script>
</head>
<body  class='default'>
    <div id="demo4_box" class="box message" data-minwidth="75" data-minheight="50">
        <div id="bar" class="handle bar"><h2> window1</h2></div>
        <div id="content" class="contents"><canvas id="canvas1" width="100" height="100"></canvas></div>
        <div id="slider" class="handle resize">//</div>
    </div> 
    <div id='jqxWidget'>
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
            <div style='margin-top: 20px;'>
            <div style='float: left;'>
                <input type="button" value="Export to Excel" id='excelExport' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

data loader js file

```
function loadData()
{
    var loadedData = new Array();
    $document).ready(function () {
        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON("api/DB/",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                loadedData.push(val);
            }); init();
        });
    });
    return loadedData
}
```

window maker js file

```
function makeWindow( )
{
    $(window).load(function () {

        $('#demo4_box').bind('dragstart', function (event) {

            return $(event.target).is('.handle');
        }).bind('drag', function (event) {
            $(this).css({
                top: event.offsetY,
                left: event.offsetX
            });
        });

        $(".resize").bind('dragstart', function (event) {
            var $box = $(this).closest(".box");

            $box.data("width", $box.width());
            $box.data("height", $box.height());
            $box.data("x", event.offsetX);
            $box.data("y", event.offsetY);

        }).bind("drag", function (event) {
            var $box = $(this).closest(".box");

            $box.width(Math.max($box.data("width") - $box.data("x") + event.offsetX, $box.data("minwidth")));
            $box.height(Math.max($box.data("height") - $box.data("y") + event.offsetY, $box.data("minheight")));
        });
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.noConflict()` . May be its the `$` sign is conflicting with some other extension. Also make sure you have specified `jquery.min.js` file in the head.

And please mention the code for review.

Comment: The only part of this that's totally valid is saying they should post their code, and that's a comment not an answer. The rest is purely speculation.

Comment: yes I do have a jquery reference I tried a few version, all the same.  As I gather the $.noConflict(); must be use before each reference to a $? I gave that a try but no luck. Though I really thing that is close to the issue. Is there a way to check the $ with a debugger and see?

Comment: I tried this, is this permissible?    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../www/jQWidgets/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" >
       $$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script> then I just use $$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The relative urls you're using to include scripts seem like likely culprits...

`../../www/<Blah>` seems like it would be valid on a *nix file system so loading the file in a browser directly (bypassing the webserver) may be able to find your scripts, however, when the site is being server at (say) `www.example.com/test.html`, there are no virtual directory levels to go "up".

The easiest way to diagnose if this is the problem is to use Firebug / the Chrome developer console and go to the networking tab. Set the filter to Javascript and see if it's actually retrieving the correct JS files.

This brings us to a commonly used but still slightly hacky workaround - the concept of a base url. Since you want your page to be able to work whether it's at

- example.com/Test.html
- example.com/MyApp/Test.html
- example.com/MyApp/User/EditProfile.html

and since you can't always know where it's going to be deployed or if the apparent, virtual URL is in any way related to the logical url (eg for SEO reasons, sometimes `/Find.php?Term=Bob` is sometimes mapped to `/Find/Bob`) you need a standardised way to reference source files.

If you *know* you'll be running at the root of the virtual directory path, use urls that are relative to `/` eg `/static/scripts/jquery.js`. If, on the other hand you might be deployed at different locations, it's common to use the server-side scripting language to populate a `base url` variable.

assuming PHP that might look like...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$BaseUrl;?>static/scripts/jquery.js">
```

How you'd determine the `$BaseUrl` depends on the application - some do it automatically by clever checking of the request url, using knowledge of the logical file system and url rewriting rules, others set it as a configuration option.

Incidentally, functions have scope, same as any variable - so declaring a function inside a function means it will only exist as long as the parent function has a reference to it or a variable with greater scope points to it. eg...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    func = function() {
        alert('ok1');
    }

    function func2() {
        alert('ok2');
    }

    func(); //Will work
    func2(); //Will work
});

func(); //Won't work for 2 reasons - one it's lost scope, 2 it will execute _before_ document is ready so before func has even been defined
func2(); //Won't work - same reasons
```

but.....

```
var superfunc;

function func() {
    alert('ok1');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    superfunc = function(){alert('super');}
    func(); //Will work, document will be ready    
}

func(); //Will work but document won't be ready
superfunc(); //Won't work until after document is ready
```

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) for a more detailed explanation